# Use search function on a website with Python Requests(ebay)

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to create a Python program using the Requests library that searches ebay for an item that they enter. Rather than hard-coding the url, is it possible to use requests library to perform an Ebay search (or a search on any website)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want here is to input a text in a search element. According to [realpython](https://realpython.com):

> The requests library is the de facto standard for making HTTP requests in Python.

I would recommend to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) to control the website's source code such as inputting a text in an element and press a button on the website.

However, if you still want to use *requests* then try to find their api endpoint which handle the searching part and use POST method to get data from it.

`resp = requests.post(url)`

Answer (score 0):

I created and Ebay developer account to access the API then wrote a small script to search eBay for historical pricing on an item. Save it an call is search.py and call it like this:

./search.py "ebay item you are looking for"

You can change the itemFilter to your liking, currently it is set for solditems for since 10-10-2019.  The complete list is here: https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/types/ItemFilterType.html

The comments at the bottom show the complete set of fields returned from Ebay, you can pick and choose the fields you like and add them to a print statement.

Also, this script will return for than the first page of items and each page costs you one of your 5,000 developer queries for the day.  I am unable to get it to work with the sandbox, not matter what I try.  I believe the Ebay sandbox is broken.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from ebaysdk.finding import Connection
import sys

DEBUG = False

#search_keywords = "2019 Hot Wheels Dumbo" 
search_keywords =  sys.argv[1]
print ("Search Keywords: " + search_keywords)


# Function accepts keywords for query and pageNumber of search to pull
# Ebay will only return 100 items per search
def build_request( keywords, pageNumber):

   # Create a request structure
   # Item Filter List https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/types/ItemFilterType.html

   request = {
        'keywords': keywords,
        'itemFilter': [
            {'name': 'condition', 'value': 'new' ,
             'name': 'SoldItemsOnly', 'value': True ,
             'name': 'EndTimeFrom',   'value': '2019-10-10T00:00:00.000Z' }
        ],
        'paginationInput': {
            'entriesPerPage': 100, # EBay limits API Calls to 100 items per page
            'pageNumber': pageNumber
        },
        'sortOrder': 'PricePlusShippingLowest',
   }
   return (request)

# Connect using yaml file to EBAY-US production site
# put in __main__  just in case we turn this into a module later
if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = Connection(config_file='ebay.yaml', debug=False, siteid="EBAY-US")
    #api = Connection(config_file='ebay.yaml', debug=False, domain="api.sandbox.ebay.com", siteid="EBAY-US")

# Run the request
query=build_request(search_keywords, 1)
query['paginationInput']['pageNumber'] = 1
response = api.execute('findCompletedItems', query)

if DEBUG:
    print (response.dict())   #Use this to see the dictionary structure

# Display how many entries and results are returned

print("API Call: findCompletedItems")
print("----------------------------")
print(f"totalEntries: {response.reply.paginationOutput.totalEntries}, totalPages: {response.reply.paginationOutput.totalPages}")
maxpage = int(str(response.reply.paginationOutput.totalPages)) + 0


# Display item information fields from the request, see below for all possible fields
for item in response.reply.searchResult.item:
    print(f"Date: {item.listingInfo.endTime} Title: {item.title}, Price: {item.sellingStatus.currentPrice.value} Shipping: {item.shippingInfo.shippingServiceCost.value}")

# Now run the request for each page and change the page in the request each time

for page in range (2,maxpage):

    print ("**** PAGE: "+str(page) +" of "+ str(maxpage)+ " ****")
    # Rebuild the Request and Update the Page Number

    # Run the request 
    query['paginationInput']['pageNumber'] = page 
    response = api.execute('findCompletedItems', query)

    # Display item information fields from the request, see below for all possible fields
    for item in response.reply.searchResult.item:
        print(f"Date: {item.listingInfo.endTime} Title: {item.title}, Price: {item.sellingStatus.currentPrice.value} Shipping: {item.shippingInfo.shippingServiceCost.value}")


#{'ack': 'Success', 'version': '1.13.0', 'timestamp': '2019-10-16T01:28:25.891Z', 
#
#searchResult': {'item': [{'itemId': '123719989207', 'title': '2019 HOT WHEELS 2 SET CORVETTE STINGRAY SUPER CHROMES 5/5 TREASURE HUNT PAIR', 'globalId': 'EBAY-US', 'primaryCategory': {'categoryId': '180506', 'categoryName': 'Contemporary Manufacture'}, 'galleryURL': 'https://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mFuyRQgYjSutGli33dqsqcA/140.jpg', 'viewItemURL': 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/2019-HOT-WHEELS-2-SET-CORVETTE-STINGRAY-SUPER-CHROMES-5-5-TREASURE-HUNT-PAIR-/123719989207', 'paymentMethod': 'PayPal', 'autoPay': 'false', 'postalCode': '54650', 'location': 'Onalaska,WI,USA', 'country': 'US', 'shippingInfo': {'shippingServiceCost': {'_currencyId': 'USD', 'value': '6.0'}, 'shippingType': 'Flat', 'shipToLocations': 'Worldwide', 'expeditedShipping': 'false', 'oneDayShippingAvailable': 'false', 'handlingTime': '2'}, 'sellingStatus': {'currentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'USD', 'value': '9.0'}, 'convertedCurrentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'USD', 'value': '9.0'}, 'sellingState': 'Ended'}, 'listingInfo': {'bestOfferEnabled': 'false', 'buyItNowAvailable': 'false', 'startTime': '2019-04-02T22:14:03.000Z', 'endTime': '2019-10-02T18:44:49.000Z', 'listingType': 'StoreInventory', 'gift': 'false', 'watchCount': '2'}, 'returnsAccepted': 'false', 'condition': {'conditionId': '1000', 'conditionDisplayName': 'New'}, 'isMultiVariationListing': 'false', 'topRatedListing': 'false'}, 
#
#
#{'itemId': '153679182310', 'title': "Hot Wheels 2019 Super Treasure Hunt '68 Mercury Cougar Loose 1/64 STH Green", 'globalId': 'EBAY-US', 'primaryCategory': {'categoryId': '73252', 'categoryName': 'Collections & Lots'}, 'galleryURL': 'https://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mEN9EsbCJY0wb6WzXjO8hNg/140.jpg', 'viewItemURL': 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Hot-Wheels-2019-Super-Treasure-Hunt-68-Mercury-Cougar-Loose-1-64-STH-Green-/153679182310', 'paymentMethod': 'PayPal', 'autoPay': 'false', 'location': 'Malaysia', 'country': 'MY', 'shippingInfo': {'shippingServiceCost': {'_currencyId': 'USD', 'value': '9.0'}, 'shippingType': 'Flat', 'shipToLocations': 'Worldwide', 'expeditedShipping': 'false', 'oneDayShippingAvailable': 'false', 'handlingTime': '15'}, 'sellingStatus': {'currentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'USD', 'value': '9.9'}, 'convertedCurrentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'USD', 'value': '9.9'}, 'bidCount': '1', 'sellingState': 'Ended'}, 'listingInfo': {'bestOfferEnabled': 'false', 'buyItNowAvailable': 'false', 'startTime': '2019-10-10T04:13:32.000Z', 'endTime': '2019-10-15T04:13:32.000Z', 'listingType': 'Auction', 'gift': 'false', 'watchCount': '1'}, 'returnsAccepted': 'false', 'condition': {'conditionId': '3000', 'conditionDisplayName': 'Used'}, 'isMultiVariationListing': 'false', 'topRatedListing': 'false'}], 
#
#'_count': '100'}, 'paginationOutput': {'pageNumber': '3', 'entriesPerPage': '100', 'totalPages': '40', 'totalEntries': '3966'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape eBay using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library.

In order not to enter the full URL of the request, you can set [`params`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) in which the necessary request parameters will be indicated and the input of the question itself for the search:

```py
query = input('Your query is: ')

params = {
    '_nkw': query,           # search query  
    '_pgn': 1                # page number
    #'LH_Sold': '1'          # shows sold items
}
```

If using `requests` library the request might be blocked as default `user-agent` in `requests` library is a [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) so website understands that's it's a bot or a script that sends a request. [Check what's your user-agent](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/).

An additional step besides providing browser user-agent could be to [rotate `user-agent`](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents), for example, to switch between PC, mobile, and tablet, as well as between browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on.

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-ebay-with-input-query-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}

query = input('Your query is: ')

params = {
    '_nkw': query,           # search query  
    '_pgn': 1                # page number
    #'LH_Sold': '1'          # shows sold items
}

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html', params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    print(f"Extracting page: {params['_pgn']}")

    print("-" * 10)
    
    for products in soup.select(".s-item__info"):
        title = products.select_one(".s-item__title span").text
        price = products.select_one(".s-item__price").text
        link = products.select_one(".s-item__link")["href"]
        
        data.append({
          "title" : title,
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })

    if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
Your query is: shirt    # query entry example
Extracting page: 1
----------
[
  {
    "title": "Men's Polo Shirt 100% Cotton Knockout Jeans NVY WHT 220 Stripe MEDIUM Free Ship",
    "price": "$11.99",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/133992813518?hash=item1f329813ce:g:tWMAAOSwXBxhTP7Q&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAwJ9%2BDbqKGCoZye6JelYY1tJHQWotUalKHQJ%2FixwyplnvOC60SofXkLVsNgRfoX09uOZLerjkBtwcW%2FQQa1wmJ6%2BYVEEagzH1GAK6Bx4rX%2BRNnj9g6SlvB2WagWETpbmrLdiFHGTIRvAL2EvfXDRqPFnEGWZ2nk%2BM0zEkiGzp%2F4ADUbPslGui3zTDJsIgVpXjAHzL2EUH3s7tiOxtd3qVTXxaE095evq5YrBgkJFJu4KB5o%2F%2BCiCURfy7xR%2FbTU7mnQ%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABlBMUJavlrOEYQ"
  },
  {
    "title": "5 Pack Oroblu Micromodal Perfect Line Round Neck Short Sleeve T-Shirt",
    "price": "$192.00",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/275287531865?hash=item40186a6159:g:OtUAAOSweKFiZr2S&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAsMRLg1VeYAIKHTiXXdD8xv56DpaeH6jc3EhFP26RJ66bqmlzXHQrMMxuo78x6S2i8DfxvuzjbXrpmYYdyRLhzgQCoaauMNvRwVNuhx11qorNlPoHrig%2BdIGG2RB4xHmXdB2fjOciLCsdYkL23jaH23ehXakQu%2BrBzER%2F2v94Sdg%2BkchjwWmRidsv0kPfLRcpiy%2BOeDBHEas4i9EQY%2F0VAzLGj2U%2FwLdcqjqSjgngj%2BRr%7Ctkp%3ABlBMUJavlrOEYQ"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [Ebay Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/ebay-organic-results) from SerpApi. It`s a paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend.

Example code that paginates through all pages with input query:

```py
from serpapi import EbaySearch
import os, json

query = input('Your query is: ')

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # serpapi api key    
    "engine": "ebay",                 # search engine
    "ebay_domain": "ebay.com",        # ebay domain
    "_nkw": query,                    # search query
    "_pgn": 1                         # page number                    
    #"LH_Sold": "1"                   # shows sold items
}

search = EbaySearch(params)           # where data extraction happens

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dict

    if "error" in results:
        print(results["error"])
        break
    
    for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
        link = organic_result.get("link")
        price = organic_result.get("price")

        data.append({
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })
                    
    page_num += 1
    print(page_num)
    
    if "next" in results.get("pagination", {}):
        params['_pgn'] += 1

    else:
        break

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$25.99",
      "extracted": 25.99
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/285018595898?hash=item425c6ea23a:g:mT0AAOSwBjljAFsl&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAkI1P1C%2BE2boIutliCMWXCADm%2BXyUp2a6Q1qOjpifaAIo6%2FWD0yHCd8Mejyfc2jc%2BQ5zzVcITrcWM0XxIfiSUILMZFsMewB154skl5re5%2FS8W9kRrabjRdy%2BoC6aQoS%2FWGq%2F6A%2BZWQ1GQkcd5Tstamu%2FgzZKoL6VYfO4YpC4oO4Im23h0wiIfI0%2BxPG8uuFRMPw%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR_i1vbKEYQ"
  },
  {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$14.16",
      "extracted": 14.16
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/234347615312?hash=item369034d450:g:hvYAAOSwNspg0TAH&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA0B1m3DPC4q0R4AQp6MO8rXnKt6qFIX2p%2BaypmySYXkIvi6XE3FHzpbtN%2B%2Bvd9P3TZPYu3fuQVl5kH0ZYDO5eqtnjh1EcZ%2Fb9rZMlMx6r6RcH%2B5wOY7X65bvRcmQ7OUmoaNGAMOZpOc4hg8vHj2afxCa%2FR7F3jDr1KjnHk%2BKnln3opoiqAVMFIoXv338f70KZw8CDd%2Fg9xU0jQlzgxDpDwSL6Y6OMz0oKxh4T%2BRUMKHj03VE5E9%2B8VKzPUMWAQ%2BZWuZyGMpWxwzn%2BomggywV5RhI%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR_i1vbKEYQ"
  },
  # ...
]
```